# How to access firebase services from flutter android app in blocked device?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am using firebase-store and firebase-auth in my flutter application. In some custom android devices, googleapis is blocked (and not possible to enable them). For such case, how do I make my app work.

I was thinking of creating a middleware (js based server) to which the app can communicate and the middleware will handle the firebase calls. But there are lots of stuffs in the app that requires firebase and migrating them all is kind of difficult. What could some other possible ways be?

Is there anyway to proxy firebase (googleapis) call from the app itself, maybe only for the app?

Comment: what's the reason for your app being blocked?

Comment: @Texv we have custom devices which will block the google services inclusing any firebase related apis.